# How to sort full date in ascending order in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have created and stored data in the table. I want to sort my table date 'dd-mm-yy' in ascending order.

I have used the following query

```
Select  DISTINCT * 
from contactdetails  
where leadsource != 'Cold Calling outgoing' 
ORDER BY dates ASC
```

I want to select all table columns from the table. Query run successfully but date not sorted proper order. (dd-mm-yy). After running the above query I have got a date in the following order

[image: date output after query run]

Please help me guys how can I sort the full date in a proper way?

Thanks.

Comment: What data type is the columns `dates`. And why the `distinct *`? As the `*` includes the primary key column of the table, there won't be any duplicates to be removed to begin with.

Comment: dates data type is varchar. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: **Never**, ever store date values in a `varchar` column - that column should have been defined as `date`. Your current problem is a direct result of the bad table definition. Those aren't "dates" but strings, and thus it's sorted as a string which means `3` is bigger than `10` and `jan` is bigger than `dec`.  Do you have a chance to fix the broken table design before you continue?

Comment: yes, please give me any suggestions.

Comment: `alter table contactdetails alter dates type date using to_date(dates, 'dd-mon-yyyy');`

Comment: Varchar (and text) are only used for stuff that doesn't fit in a proper validated data type. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html